# Changed position of carousel to absolute and caused other <div>s to move as well. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, carousel, overlapping

I had an issue with my carousel where there was a gap (whitespace) on the right side of the carousel. I read on here that a good solution would be to set the position of .carousel to absolute. When I did that it worked! However, it also shifted my other  up and now there is text overlapping the carousel.

```
<div id='home' class='row'>
<div class='col-12 p-0'>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
    <div id='caroselHeight'class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active container-fluid">
            <img src="sky1c.jpg" class='img-fluid' alt="First Slide">
            <div id='titleCard' class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h1 id='cloudFontH'>Welcome To My Portfolio</h1>
                <small>Slide right to view my projects</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
            <img src="slide02.jpg" class='img-fluid' alt="Second Slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
            <img src="slide03.jpg" class='img-fluid' alt="Third Slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my carousel and this is the css for it

```
.carousel-inner{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height : 600px;
}
.carousel{
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
}
#home{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the section that is overlapping

```
<div id='aboutSection'>
        <div>
        <img src='craft.png' id='craft'>
        </div>
<section id='about'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <h1 id='cloudFontH' class='text-center'>About Me</h1>
                <p id='cloudFontT' class='text-center'>
                    I am a student at the University of New Orleans. I am persuing a degree in computer science with a 
                    minor in math. 
                </p>
```

I'm not going to show the whole  as that is basically all of my code and I feel like I'm already posting too much. 
Lastly the css

```
#aboutSection{
    background-image: url("sky1.jpg");
    height: auto;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Again sorry about posting SO MUCH code, I'm not sure if it is helpful or not but I hope it is. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It might help if you link to the question where you found the previous advice.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you set something's position as absolute - it no longer takes up space on the page, so other things can move into the same space it was taking up.

Using `position: absolute` to get rid of a little bit of unwanted whitespace is overkill.  I recommend you look for a different technique to get rid of just the little bit of whitespace, instead of... all the space.